# Problems with truck route violation

Tags: routes, here-api

We are using truck routing and we have encountered an issue where we are not sure how does the **truck route violation** trigger.
Following example on the documentation page:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/example-truck-route-violating-restriction.html

if you send the following request:

`https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={YOUR API KEY}&mode=fastest;truck&waypoint0=geo!52.534924,13.199499&waypoint1=geo!52.534614,13.199362&height=5&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&routeattributes=notes&maneuverattributes=notes`

you will see that there is a **note** property coming that tells that there has been a **violation**. Yet, if you try to do another request (other than example from documentation), you will see that the "note" property is coming empty (without violation). We are using the route from Manhattan to Jersey City through bridge, using parameters width=50, height=50 and length=150 across narrow streets. This is the request:

`https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={YOUR API KEY}&mode=fastest;truck&waypoint0=geo!40.71650771367789,-74.00330338450901&waypoint1=geo!40.78629608681962,-74.0084639992997&height=50&width=50&length=150&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&routeattributes=notes&maneuverattributes=notes`

Yet, you will see that the **note** property is empty, meaning the violation has not been triggered, despite extreme parameters that should definitely trigger violations.

Can you please explain us how exactly is the violation triggered and how should the request look like if want to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the routing algorithm was able to find a route that would satisfy your conditions without violating. As you can see it has rerouted(route that doesn't pass through bridge) when you provide height which is more than the allowed limit for the bridge.
[image]

However if you force it to passthrough the bridge(by adding it has a waypoint) then it gives a violation as expected.

[https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={your-api-key}&mode=fastest;truck&waypoint0=geo!40.71650771367789,-74.00330338450901&waypoint1=40.763687,-74.010802&waypoint2=geo!40.78629608681962,-74.0084639992997&height=50&width=50&length=150&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&routeattributes=notes&maneuverattributes=notes](https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=%7Byour-api-key%7D&mode=fastest;truck&waypoint0=geo!40.71650771367789,-74.00330338450901&waypoint1=40.763687,-74.010802&waypoint2=geo!40.78629608681962,-74.0084639992997&height=50&width=50&length=150&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&routeattributes=notes&maneuverattributes=notes)

The above query forces the route to passthrough the bridge(waypoint1=40.763687,-74.010802). You can find the below violation in the response:
[image]